# DB2 Funktion does not work, Error Code SQLCODE=-104

Tags: function, db2

I just want to write a function in DB2, which gets two doubles (x and Y) and counts SQRT((X*X) + (Y*Y)). I always get the error Code:
`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;SQRT((X*X) + (Y*Y));END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.13.80`

This is the function:

`CREATE FUNCTION R (X DOUBLE, Y DOUBLE)
   RETURNS DOUBLE
   RETURN SQRT((X*X) + (Y*Y));`

I don't get it, what is wrong?

Comment: How do you create it (command line, tool)? What is the configured statement terminator?

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on Windows against db2 express c and it runs ok if you drop the ;